# Implementing a walkthrough for an Android application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and want to make an in-app walkthrough when the application is launched for the first time.

What is the best approach for implementing this and integrating it with my application?

Comment: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/showcase-view/